# jPlayer flash fallback doesn't buffer?

Tags: jquery, flash, video-streaming, jplayer

The flash fallback for my jPlayer instance doesn't seem to stream videos in IE8 and below. Instead, it waits until the entire video is downloaded and then plays it! Kind of an issue, considering my average video takes 2 minutes to download.

Here's the options:

```
// DASHBOARD JPLAYER: Load first video from #vidlist, set title
var vid2 = $j('#videos').find('option:nth-child(2)').val();
var name2 = $j('#videos').find('option:nth-child(2)').html();

$j('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        $j(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            m4v: vid2+".mp4",
            ogv: vid2+".ogv",
            webm: vid2+".webm"
        });
    },
    swfPath: "/wp-content/plugins/jplayer", 
    supplied: "webmv, ogv, m4v",
    size: {
        width: "320px",
        height: "180px",
        cssClass: "jp-video-180p"
    },
    solution: "html,flash"
    //errorAlerts:true,
    //warningAlerts:true
});
```

The filename 'vid2' is an absolute path, and the swfPath is working fine. Do you see any immediate errors? Is there a way to force streaming or buffering?

Comment: is your server returning the correct MIME types for M4V, OGV and WebM requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your M4V and FLV file are encoded with the metadata in the beginning, not the end. The video will not play until metadata is downloaded.

Per http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-media-encoding

"The metadata should be at the start of the encoded data, since the Flash solution must have the metadata in order to begin playling."

Answer (score 0):

Ensure server returning the correct MIME types for M4V, OGV and WebM requests.